# How can I build a multi-level expandable navigate UI?

Tags: android

I want to build a menu for restaurant. This is a tablet app, not on phone. The UI requires 3 parts. The left one is desired with a 2-level expandable navigation. When the client click one first-level item, system displays its second-level items. When the client change one first-level item, the new one will expand and the old one will automatically close. While client click a second-level item, the middle part will display the dishes in this category. Please refer the picture.
[Main UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mJI2.jpg)

Then, how should I design these parts? Can I put all in one activity? Or put 3 fragments for the 3 parts? I don't know if there are some differences of loading and refresh efficiency between the 2 ways.

Answer (score 1):

[expandable navigation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view)

[expandable navigation](https://github.com/wjie2014/DoubleListViewLinkage)

[Shopping Cart Click](https://github.com/ChyengJason/ShoppingCart)

[fragment](https://github.com/YoKeyword/Fragmentation)

First do three functions in two pieces

Comment: Thank you so much, I never know there are so many examples on github

Comment: Not at all. I enjoyed it.